# Translate requests' URLs to a web server to fetch pages

Tags: linux, proxy, webserver

I'm on a server (under Red Hat), let say server A, which has access to the web server B but not web server C.

Server B and server C are the exact same with different host names and different base paths for urls.

A web page will be the exact same if accessed like:

- http://server-b-hostname/path-a/page-x-uri
- or: http://server-c-hostname/path-b/page-x-uri

I need to make server A "believe" that he can fetch pages from server C (with server C's urls) while he is fetching on server B.

I was imagining kind of a small proxy doing the job, but maybe there is something even simpler.
Do you know how can I manage to achieve this?

[image: proxy-idea]

I would love to have the simpler solution to solve this, performances are not really an issue.

Comment: Just a precision: I don't need to modify the fetched pages / contents themselves

Comment: Can you just add an entry to `/etc/hosts` so `server-c` resolves to `server-b`'s address?

Comment: @EricRenouf No, because the server b doesn't understand server c url calls. Basically, server b will answer with 404. And I'm not even talking about that both urls have different base paths (path-b and path-c in the diagram). I already thought about that, thanks though ;)

Comment: Looks like I will need to use an apache with reverse proxy...